# What yaml build command to put to run sonar cloud for github repo?

Tags: sonarqube, github-actions

I have followed all the steps to setup to run my github repo for sonar cloud scan. I am not sure what to put under `<your build command>`.

[image]

When I leave it empty, I got an error when running the job at github action.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the command already, `dotnet build`